# How can I convert a TypeScript object to a plain object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using a JS library, specifically `select2` that acts a tad differently than I'd like if the objects I'm passing it aren't plain objects. This is all checked by using jQuery's `isPlainObject` function.

Does TypeScript have a cast I'm unaware of that would achieve this without resorting to writing my own?

```
class Opt {
    constructor(public id, public text) {

    }

    toPlainObj(): Object {
        return {
            id: this.id,
            text: this.text
        }
    }
}

let opts = [
    new Opt(0, 'foo'),
    new Opt(1, 'bar')
];

console.clear()

console.log('both should be false')
$.map(opts, opt => {
    console.log($.isPlainObject(opt))
})

console.log('both should be true')
$.map(opts, opt => {
    console.log($.isPlainObject(opt.toPlainObj()))
})
```

Comment: please post your code here

Comment: @messerbill I don't believe SO code snippets support TypeScript. At least, I can't get it to work.

Comment: just type it here - you dont need to use the code snippet functionality

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
class Point {
    private x: number;
    private y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    getX(): number {
        return this.x;
    }

    getY(): number {
        return this.y;
    }
}

let p1 = new Point(4, 5);
let p2 = Object.assign({}, p1);
```

`p1` is the class instance, and `p2` is just `{ x: 4, y: 5 }`.

And with the `toPlainObj` method:

```
class Point {
    private x: number;
    private y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    getX(): number {
        return this.x;
    }

    getY(): number {
        return this.y;
    }

    toPlainObj(): { x: number, y: number } {
        return Object.assign({}, this);
    }
}
```

If this is something you need in more classes then you can have a base class which has this method:

```
class BaseClass<T> {
    toPlainObj(): T {
        return Object.assign({}, this);
    }
}

class Point extends BaseClass<{ x: number, y: number }> {
    private x: number;
    private y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        super();

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    getX(): number {
        return this.x;
    }

    getY(): number {
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I was just about to blow a fuse, but this answer saved me from that :)

Comment: I'm looking for the exact opposite. Have plain js object, want to convert it to a specific type.

Comment: @Moulde something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314791/how-to-instantiate-an-object-in-typescript-by-specifying-each-property-and-its-v ?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this will not convert any of the objects properties into JS objects, they will remain as instances of whichever type they are. See the following example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8C+AoFpIwEKJdaADgK4BGIAlsNAG5ggBcc0AvNAHYCmA7nABQCUAbhSoUIDgBdoADxbtu0LAOEo6HAE4Tes8mwgSwbYBwD2AM0VDoAemvQAKuqIdV4zdoB0tENF37DxuZwVrYOTi5iktAAnnIA8iQAVhzAEh6Y5ADmbLzIADQyQmhq7rF+BkamFlghdgBidBAuJVrRXnS+ehWBFrC1Yc4oQA

Comment: @Qyaffer do you know of any way to also convert object instance properties to plain objects?

Answer (score 10):

Something like this is simple and it works :

```
let plainObj;
try {
    plainObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
}
```

Comment: Messed up the dates in the object.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to destructure the object. Something like this: `{...myObject}`

Answer (score 0):

`Lodash` internal functions are unsung heros. They are not exported by default. `_baseClone` can do that. I do this in my angular project.

```
import * as baseClone from 'lodash/_baseClone'

const classObj = getComplexClassObject();
const flatObj = baseClone(classObj, 7);
```

`7` because `1 | 2 | 4`. Deep Flag, Flat Flag, Symbols Flag, respectively. Check it out, [_baseClone.js](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.21-npm/_baseClone.js).

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, however in Nitzan's answer above, the typescript syntax checker seems to be ok with just doing the following:

```ts
const plainObj:any = ClassObj;
ClassObj.newProperty = "Test";
```

So it seems like there is no real need to use Object.assign unless there is a difference I am unaware of.