# How to instantiate an object in TypeScript by specifying each property and its value?

Tags: typescript, syntax, instance, instantiation

Here's a snippet in which I instantiate a new `content` object in my service:

```
const newContent = new Content(
     result.obj.name
     result.obj.user.firstName,
     result.obj._id,
     result.obj.user._id,
);
```

The problem is that this way of object instantiation relies on the order of properties in my `content` model. I was wondering if there's a way to do it by mapping every property to the value I want to set it to, for example:

```
 const newContent = new Content(
     name: result.obj.name,
     user: result.obj.user.
     content_id: result.obj._id,
     user_id: result.obj.user._id,
 );
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
const newContent = <Content>({
    name: result.obj.name,
    user: result.obj.user.
    content_id: result.obj._id,
    user_id: result.obj.user._id,
 });
```

Here you can instantiate an object and use type assertion or casting to the Content type.
For more information on type assertion: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions

Comment: It is clear what you have changed, but it would be useful to say why.  Teaching moments everywhere.

Comment: This is actually very very wrong! You're not instantiating an instance of `Content` here, you are creating a simple object which has the same members. If for example `Content` would have a method `fn`, then in your example this will fail: `newContent.fn()`.

Comment: this answer will work if you extend the prototype of the object like so:
`const newContent = <Content>(_.extend({...}, Content.prototype));`

Comment: As noted earlier, this would only work for an interface, which is what I'm using it for.

Answer (score 13):

You can pass an object to the constructor which wraps all of those variables:

```
type ContentData = {
    name: string;
    user: string;
    content_id: string;
    user_id: string;
}

class Content {
    constructor(data: ContentData) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then:

```
const newContent = new Content({
     name: result.obj.name,
     user: result.obj.user.
     content_id: result.obj._id,
     user_id: result.obj.user._id,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a C# background where object initializers are taken for granted, I too wanted to see if something similar in syntax could be achieved in typescript to initialize data fields without too much repetition/boilerplate, here's the code I came up with:

```
type FunctionProp<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never }[keyof T];
type Fields<T> = Omit<T, FunctionProp<T>>;
type PartialFields<T> = Partial<Fields<T>>;

class User {}
class Content {
    public name!: string;
    public user!: User; 
    public content_id!: string; 
    public user_id!: string;

    constructor(obj: Fields<Content>) { 
        for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
            (this as any)[key] = (obj as any)[key];
        }
    }

    print() { console.log(this.name); }
}

const content = new Content({
    name: "test",
    user: new User(),
    user_id: "USER-001",
    content_id: "CONTENT-001"
});
console.log(content);
// Output: Content {name: 'test', user: User, content_id: 'CONTENT-001', user_id: 'USER-001'}
```

It makes initializing simple data objects (DTOs, POCOs) a bit more readable and less error-prone in my opinion. `PartialFields<Content>` can be used instead of `Fields<Content>` in the constructor to accommodate for optional properties in the initializer.