# creating (instantiate) a typescript object of declared type

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular(6) Router "Params" object is declared as follows:

```
export declare type Params = {
    [key: string]: any;
};
```

Is it an error to instantiate it as follows? -

```
newParams = new Params();
```

Than add items to it as follows:

```
params.push({name: value});
```

Pycharm says I cannot initialize the way I do. Is Params a type or some kind of higher level type that needs to be treated other way?

Comment: Yes, it's an error. The TS compiler tells you as much: `'Params' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` Also if you want to have a `push` method you should really define that explicitly, not as part of a general index signature. If you want to `new` something up you need to define a *class*.

Answer (score 2):

Where the Params type `alias` is used, it's telling you that it is (or expects) an object literal with key|value pairs, with the value being of type `any`

```
export declare type Params = {
    [key: string]: any;
};
```

It's not a `class`, so you cannot instantiate it. [Officially](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) it's called a `type alias`, and acts more like an interface than a class, but with some differences e.g. cannot be implemented by a class

It's not terribly helpful, as every object can have key|value pairs, but aliases are used in some cases for documentation purposes

In the *ActivatedRoute* documentation, we can see that the `params` Observable returns objects of type `Params` - so we know there will be values we can access using property accessor bracket notation `route.snapshot.params["id"];`

```
params  Observable<Params>  
An observable of the matrix parameters scoped to this route
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess it's more complicated than that, but the simple answer is, just initialize it with an empty object as follows:

```
const params: Params = {};
```

Took it from the Angular open source... sometimes the best way is just to dig in the sources :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
type ErrorResponse = {
  message: string;
};

const error: ErrorResponse = { message: 'Ups' };
```

Another alternative as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314791/how-to-instantiate-an-object-in-typescript-by-specifying-each-property-and-its-v):

```
const error = <ErrorResponse>{ message: 'Ups' };
```