# Send just the model PK (or any other field) for nested model in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

Having the following sample models:

```js
interface User {
  id: string
  organization: Organization
}

interface Organization {
  id: string
}
```

When I send a request, for example:

```js
const user = new User("abc", new Organization("xyz"))
httpClient.post<User>(url, user)
```

Understandably, it looks like this:

```json
{
  "id": "abc",
  "organization": {
    "id": "xyz"
  }
}
```

How can I send a request that looks like the following, instead?

```json
{
  "id": "abc",
  "organization": "xyz"
}
```

I was hoping there would be some kind of mechanism to transform a request in `HttpClient`, but I can’t find anything.

Another approach was to convert the `User` to a plain JS object and manipulate it, but I can’t figure out how to do it:

```js
const user = new User("abc", new Organization("xyz"))
const data = Object.assign({}, user);

data.organization = data.organization.id; // error, can’t assign string to Organization
```

So `data` is still a `User`, not a plain JS object.

What’s the best way to achieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a TypeScript object to a plain object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300338/how-can-i-convert-a-typescript-object-to-a-plain-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution but I’m not 100% happy with it. I won’t accept it for now, in case someone can offer a better one.

Edit: marked as accepted answer.

```js
const user = new User("abc", new Organization("xyz"));

// clone the `user` object as I don’t want to modify the original
// (this step is optional)
const data = Object.assign({}, user);

// overwrite the `organization` property on the object
// with the value of `organization.id`
Object.assign(data, { organization: data.organization.id });

httpClient.post<User>(url, data)
```

To keep it clean, I added it as a method on the `User` class:

```js
class User
{
    constructor(
        id: string,
        organization: Organization
    ) { }

    asRequestData()
    {
        const data = Object.assign({}, this);
        Object.assign(data, { organization: data.organization?.name });

        return data;
    }
}

httpClient.post<User>(url, user.asRequestData())
```

Answer (score 0):

> So data is still a User, not a plain JS object.

You are creating an instance of User to send the data and the object data is type of `User` always.

If you want to send plain object, de-structure the objects and create one object literal:

```
const org = new Organization("xyz"), 
      user = new User("abc", {organization: org.organization.id}),             
      {id, organization} = user,
      payload = {id, organization};

// why do you need to create org or user if you can directly assign and create an object like this

// const payload = {id: "abc" , organization: "xyz" };
httpClient.post<User>(url, payload)
```

Comment: Your first solution won’t work because `organization` has to be of type `Organization`, which has an `id` property and you’re passing a plain object with `organization` property.

I know the data type is `User`. What I said was that the data type is still `User` after creating a new (seemingly plain) object with `Object.assign({}, user)`.

As to why I’m using models if I can “directly assign and create an object”: models provide data safety and, optionally, methods to manipulate the data. Plain objects can do neither.

Comment: `Object.assign({}, user)` clones/copy the object so it is also copying the type from instance, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).  `Your first solution won’t work ` yes it is possible if you have a type check in user class.

Comment: You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300338/how-can-i-convert-a-typescript-object-to-a-plain-object).